# Can you make two ACI's communicate without them beeing in a container group?

Tags: azure, docker, azure-container-instances

I have two Azure Container Instances which I would like to share data, but as they're Windows containers, I can't put them into a container group. Ideally, one of them should also not be puplically availible through the internet.

Comment: As the answer shows multiple Windows containers are not supported in a container group. So I would suggest you use the AKS with Windows nodes and share the files with Azure File share.

Comment: Using AKS is our long-term plan anyway. But we have some permission issues right now, so I was hoping there was a way to get around the container group to get a working prototype up and running, but it seems this is not the case.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Currently this is not supported.

We do have a preview feature of deploying ACI into a virtual network however we currently do not support Windows. They are working on adding windows to this feature though. Although no ETA is available.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/container-instances/container-instances-vnet#preview-limitations